# List sub pages with custom field content converting image ID to URL

Tags: images, urls, advanced-custom-fields, id

I am using the ACF plugin to create static (non-ecommerce) product pages.

I am now making a page that lists all the sub pages with product name and the image added to the product_logo custom field. I found some code that almost did everything I wanted:

```
                <?php
                //get children of page 241 and display with custom fields

                $args=array(
                  'post_parent' => 825,
                  'post_type' => 'page',
                );
                $my_query = null;
                $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
                if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {

                  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                        <div>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?>

                                <!-- here I get the 'product_short_description' custom field's data, assign it to the $meta_one variable and echo it out !-->
                                <?php $meta_one = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'product_short_description', true); ?>
                                <span><?php echo $meta_one; ?></span>

                                <!-- here I get the 'product_logo' custom field's data, assign it to the $meta_two variable and echo it out !-->
                                <?php $meta_two = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'product_logo', true); ?>
                                <span><img src="<?php echo $meta_two; ?>" /></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                   <?php endwhile; } ?>
                <?php wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().?>
```

The second field $meta_two gets the product_logo field containing the ID of the image. I wanted to convert this to a URL using:

```
  <?php wp_get_attachment_image_src($meta_two, null, true); ?>
```

But this just gives me a blank URL.

Full code below:

```
                $args=array(
                  'post_parent' => 825,
                  'post_type' => 'page',
                );
                $my_query = null;
                $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
                if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {

                  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                        <div>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?>

                                <!-- here I get the 'product_short_description' custom field's data, assign it to the $meta_one variable and echo it out !-->
                                <?php $meta_one = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'product_short_description', true); ?>
                                <span><?php echo $meta_one; ?></span>

                                <!-- here I get the 'product_logo' custom field's data, assign it to the $meta_two variable and echo it out !-->
                                <?php $meta_two = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'product_logo', true); ?>
                                <span><img src="<?php wp_get_attachment_image_src($meta_two, null, true); ?> " /></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                   <?php endwhile; } ?>
                <?php wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().?>
```

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this

```
                    <?php
                    //get children of page 241 and display with custom fields

                    $args=array(
                      'post_parent' => 825,
                      'post_type' => 'page',
                    );
                    $my_query = null;
                    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
                    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {

                      while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                            <?php $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'product_logo', true)); ?>
                            <?php $alt_text_for_logo = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'alt_text_for_logo', true); ?>
                            <div class="column small-6 medium-4 product">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                                    <span> <img src="<?php echo $img[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $alt_text_for_logo; ?>" /></span>
                                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                       <?php endwhile; } ?>
                    <?php wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().?>
            </div>
```